# How to allow writing locally on read-only NFS Partition

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, nfs, pxe

I created my own PXE/NFS network boot server on Ubuntu 12.04 as explained [here](http://www.serenux.com/2011/04/howto-create-a-diskless-workstation-that-boots-from-pxe-using-ubuntu/). I can write to files on client side if I change `/etc/exports` file like this on server side:

```
/srv/ubuntulivecd/        *(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

I want to change files only locally. I mean this shouldn't change the file on NFS partition if I write to the file on local. If i change `rw(read-write)` option to `ro(read-only)`, I can't change files (as expected) because of permissions. Is there a way to change files locally or temporary(all files have to be removed after reboot or power off) on client side ?

Comment: Changing the export to ro does not affect permissions when accessing the underlying filesystem directly on the local machine.  You do however, need to actually access the underlying filesystem directly rather than say, nfs mount the export.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Local relative what, the server or the machine that boots with PXE? Might be easier to see what you want if you tells us what you want to do on what machine.

Comment: I'm booting diskless pc via NFS. I can not create or change a file on diskless pc if I set `/srv/ubuntulivecd` directory as read-only with `ro` option on `/etc/exports` on NFS server. I want to read-write any files on diskless but this should not affect files under `/srv/ubuntulivecd` on NFS server. When I change read-only option to read-write option, It is created on NFS server if I create a file on diskless pc.